# Is the output power of nRF24L01+ dependant on power supply level?

Tags: rf, power-consumption, nrf24l01

I'm making a low power sensor node using a [nRF24L01+](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwisxdb1qbr7AhVVRPEDHYh1BCAQFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sparkfun.com%2Fdatasheets%2FComponents%2FSMD%2FnRF24L01Pluss_Preliminary_Product_Specification_v1_0.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3a8r_7HsVZ0el6FeHStSpk) module in **always-TX mode**, powered by 2xAAA batteries. Considering the minimum voltage of 2v when batteries are depleted, the device would still work since all other components are fine with it. However, nRF will be working over a supply voltage of 2.7v~3v (fully charged batteries) down to 2v. I want to know if the nRF radio power output would change considerably over this voltage range.

The values provided in datasheet (as much as I can understand) are based on 3v operation and I couldn't find something relevant to this.

Comment: The data sheet says 1.9 to 3.6 V supply range, and “on chip voltage regulator”.  As long as you don’t disable that regulator, the power output should be reasonably constant.

Comment: ...and "VDD_PA... Power Supply Output (+1.8V) for the internal nRF24L01+ Power Amplifier".